# Programmatically populate UITableViewCells - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am working on a IOS Swift based project that uses a few classes to customize the `UITableView` and the `UITableViewCell`.  Now one of my Cells inside the `UITableView` has an inner `UITableView`.  I was wondering if it is possible when inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath, that I could also populate cells programmatically in that same process.

EX:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
  ...... do stuff
  cell.detailview.uitableview <!-- populate the cells here?
  .......
  return cell
}
```

Suggestions?

Comment: https://github.com/angelvasa/AVLighterTableViewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming three different types of cells:

- `class NormalTableViewCell: UITableViewCell:` This is used for the "regular" cells of your outer (main) table view.
- `class TableContainingTableviewCell : UITableViewCell`: This is used for the "special" cells of your *outer* (main) table view, that contain a table view (inner) within themselves.
- `class InnerTableViewCell : UITableViewCell`: This is used for the cells of your inner table views (those contained in cells of class `TableContainingTableviewCell`).

***(Replace each by your actual class names).***

, you can use this code:

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // This can also be done in storyboard with prototype cells:
    self.tableView.registerClass(NormalTableViewCell.class, forCellReuseIdentifier: normalCellIdentifier)
    self.tableView.registerClass(TableContainingTableViewCell.class, forCellReuseIdentifier: specialCellIdentifier)
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, 
    cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath
) -> UITableViewCell 
{
    if tableView == self.tableView {
        // [A] OUTER TABLE VIEW

        if indexPath == index path of table-containing cell {
            // (A.1) TABLE-CONTAINING CELL

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(specialCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableContainingTableViewCell

            // (...configure cell...)

            // Setup and refresh inner table view: 

            cell.contentView.tableView.dataSource = self

            // This is needed for dequeueing to succeed:
            cell.contentView.tableView.registerClass(InnerTableViewCell.class, forCellReuseIdentifier: innerCellIdentifier)

            cell.contentView.tableView.reloadData()
            // ^ THIS TRIGGERS A CALL TO THIS FUNCTION, ON THE
            // INNER TABLE VIEW (PATH [B] BELOW)

            return cell
        }
        else {
            // (A.2) NORMAL CELL

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(normalCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NormalTableViewCell

            // (configure cell)

            return cell
        }
    }
    else {
        // [B] INNER TABLE VIEW

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(innerCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! InnerTableViewCell

        // (configure cell)            

        return cell
    }
}
```

---

...but I would strongly argue against having a table view embedded inside a another table view's cell. At the very least, make sure the inner table view does not need to scroll (i.e., the containing cell is high enough to show all rows and the table itself has scroll disabled).

Comment: Hmmm, I does not seem that the` UITableView` is calling my primary controller.  After my cells populate, that `UItableView `does not seem to call `cellForRowAtIndexPath` from the parent

Comment: Make sure your controller is the `dataSource` of **both** table views.

Comment: @nicolasMirari, when adding ` cell.detailView.innertableView.dataSource = self;` that seems to break it, any idea why?

Comment: What do you mean by "break it"?

Comment: I apologize for my "lack of words".  `this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key tableView.'
`

Comment: Actually Nicolas XCode decided to unbind my IBOutlet.  That is where the error was coming from, let me try your solution.

Comment: Awesome thanks,  So I keep getting,` reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier SingleOrderTableViewCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'`   Now I have a customer class with "SingleOrderTableViewCell".  Shouldn't that be substantial?

Comment: You have to register table cell classes for reuse with each table view; either on the storyboard (cell prototypes) or programmatically. This is typically done in `viewDidLoad()` when the table view is contained in a view controller.

Comment: So something similar to: `public class SingleOrderTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    private let cellIdentifier = "SingleOrderTableViewCell"

    @IBOutlet weak var test: UITextField!
    
    func viewDidLoad() {

        registerCell()
    }
    func registerCell() {
        let cellNib = UINib(nibName: cellIdentifier, bundle: nil)
        UITableViewCell.registerNib(cellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
    }
}`

Comment: That is within my UITableViewCell

Comment: Can't I also just set it also where I set the datasource?

Comment: Yes; see my edits (`cell.contentView.tableView.registerClass(InnerTableViewCell.class, forCellReuseIdentifier: innerCellIdentifier)
`)

Comment: Well what would my InnerTableViewCell.class be?  Just SingleOrderTableViewCell?

Comment: Same thing as my cell reuse identifier?

Comment: I edited my code again. However, these details are outside the scope of your original question and instead pertain to general, basic use of table views and cells. If you don't understand this, see some tutorials or guides.

Comment: @NicolasMirari, No thank you very much for all the help.  Swift just throughs me for a loop sometimes.  But quick question, InnerTableViewCell.class would be invalid?

Comment: That's what you do in Objective-C: `[InnerTableViewCell class];`. In Swift, it is `InnerTableViewCell.self`.

Comment: Thanks again for your help!  Love learning from people who know their stuff!

Comment: also why do you strongly reject implementing a UITableview inside an UITableViewCell?

Comment: Because it is not very elegant (in my opinion), and having two vertical scroll views one inside the other can be confusing for the user. Perhaps the same data can be displayed more easily using table view sections.